# Adding focus to clicked button

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, focus

I am trying to add focus to a clicked button that already triggers a hide and reveal. I'm not sure what code and where is needed. 
This is the code I have for the hide/reveal, but I want the clicked button to remain in hover color state when clicked to show it is the active one.

(I am using a divi theme, so this code is put into the code module on my current page for this functionality, not in the overall theme customizer):

```
    <style type="text/css">
/*Button Click to Open and Close*/

.once_button.closed:after {content:"";}
.once_button.opened:after{content:"";}

.monthly_button.closed:after {content:"";}
.monthly_button.opened:after{content:"";} 
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#revealO').hide();
jQuery('.once_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#revealO").toggle();
jQuery('.once_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
jQuery("#revealM").hide();
});

jQuery('#revealM').hide();
jQuery('.monthly_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#revealM").toggle();
jQuery('.monthly_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
jQuery("#revealO").hide();
});

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Removing the `e.preventDefault()` should result in the button that just got clicked to also be focused

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still will not remain the focus.